# Wordpress Assign Separate Menu to each Custom PostType's home page

Tags: wordpress

I managed to install plugin **CPT UI** and got the Custom POST URL Structure working as desired
domain/bschool , domain/jobs , domain/engg , domain/medical

Now I’m only struggling how to assign different “Menu” specific to its respective Custom Post type’s home (archive) page. Like domain/bschool has its own menu, domain/engg has its own specific and so on…

I installed another plugin **Page Specific Menu Items**, created 4 Menus and using this plugin assigned them in this order

Home-Menu (Main Menu) assigned to site’s default home page

**bschool-Menu** assigned to Custom post type **bschool**
**engg-Menu** assigned to Custom post type **engg**
**jobs-Menu** assigned to Custom post type **jobs**
**Medical-Menu** assigned to Custom post type **medical**

But it doesn’t seem to work. I see the Home-Menu (Main Menu) on inside custom post type home pages (URLs stated above) the Readme for the plugin says something the problem can be if the theme overides ‘hide_this_item’ but I’m not sure.

Any tips how to get custom Menu specific to each post type’s page ?

Answer (score 0):

You could name your menus like "menu-CPTslugname" and then in your theme file use the menu name in wp_nav_menu, where the menu name is "menu-" and concatenate the cpt slug name.